# Userform VBA to copy value into cells

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Dear Fellow StackOverFlow-members,

I've come to you with a silly question, that i just can't seem to solve.
I'm working on a userform to input data in an employee-database (within the same worksheet). 
Code is as following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Employee-Data")

iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 13) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
ThisWorkbook.Save
Unload Employee
End Sub
```

The code now uses the first row (A2 until H2) to input the data. I want it to used the first empty cell in A to input the data, so it doesn't overwrite any  filled data.

I want to learn from this, so if possible, explain me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find first empty row in column A, try...

```
iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

1 in the above code represents column A. You can either use column index or column letter like...

```
iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

Comment: Damn. Sometimes I guess i'm thinking way too hard about my code. Thank you so much for a quick fix.

Comment: You're welcome Rob! Don't worry it happens with everyone. :)